# Facing some problems with InputMismatchException in java

Tags: java

Here in my code, I have two String type ArrayList **arr** and **arr2**. **arr** ArrayList is for storing the pair of lines and here int **t** is for the number of pairs that user enters in **arr**.
The Second ArrayList **arr2** is for storing a single line and integer **t2** is the number of a single line that a users stores in **arr2**. After that I have simply print **arr** and **arr2**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arr2 = new ArrayList<>();
        int t;
        t = sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            String first,second;
            first = sc.nextLine();
            second = sc.nextLine();

            arr.add(first);
            arr.add(second);
        }

         sc.nextInt();
        int t2;
        t2 = sc.nextInt();

        sc.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<t2;i++){
            String input;
            input = sc.nextLine();
            arr2.add(input);
        }

        for(String val: arr){
            System.out.println(val);
        }
          System.out.println();
        for(String val: arr2){
            System.out.println(val);
        }

    }
}
```

But after entering all the input I'm getting **Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException**

```
Sample Input-

3
ko te kader molla
tui rajakar tui rajakar
tumi ke ami ke
garo chakma bangali
jalo re jalo
agun jalo

2

jalo re jalo
ko te kader molla



Sample Output-

ko te kader molla
tui rajakar tui rajakar
tumi ke ami ke
garo chakma bangali
jalo re jalo
agun jalo

jalo re jalo
ko te kader molla
```

Comment: Consider using **meaningful variable names**. It is much easier for someone (or yourself) to follow `pairsOfLines` than `arr2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading 2 times `sc.nextInt();` after the first `for-loop`. In these lines:

```
sc.nextInt();
int t2;
t2 = sc.nextInt();
```

I believe your error comes from there as the next value is an `int` (3 in your sample input) but then you try to read another `int` but you're providing a `String`.

If this is not the issue, please post a complete Stack Trace.